# javascript, email validator script

Tags: javascript, email, validation

I'm trying to use the following javascript to validate a proper email address, but I am getting an error within this script.  Can anyone see why?  Thank you in advance.

```
function isEmail(str){
    var reg = new RegExp("?:[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*|"(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21\x23-\x5b\x5d-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])*")@(?:(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?|\[(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?|[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]:(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21-\x5a\x53-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])+)\]");
    return reg.test(str);
}
```

Comment: How come the regex pattern starts with `?:` (and not `(?:`)?

Comment: As well as the correct answers about the unescaped quote character, you should also consider not creating a new regex object for every test call.  This is unnecessary overhead.

Answer (score 0):

You have an unescaped string character. Anytime you open a string with `"`, anytime you want `"` to be in the string it needs to be escaped with a backslash, `\"`.

```
function isEmail(str){
    var reg = new RegExp("?:[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*|\"(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21\x23-\x5b\x5d-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])*\")@(?:(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?|\[(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?|[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]:(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21-\x5a\x53-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])+)\]");
    return reg.test(str);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ther error is that you have an unescaped  double quote

```
var reg = new RegExp("?:[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*|\" ....
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------^
```

Note: Just look at the color coding of your question and you will see it. Maybe your IDE has color coding too.

Comment: I've addressed the issue with the unescaped double quote, but still not working.  Any other ideas?

Comment: @user1748076 you have multiple double quotes in your string, try to escape them all

Answer (score 0):

Email validation is easy to get wrong. I therefore recommend you to use [Verimail.js](https://github.com/comfirm/Verimail.js).

Why?

- Syntax validation (according to RFC 822)
- IANA TLD validation
- Spelling suggestion for the most common TLDs and email domains
- Deny temporary email account domains such as mailinator.com

It's easy! Download and include the script on your site:

https://raw.github.com/comfirm/Verimail.js/master/src/verimail.js

Then use:

```
var email = "cool@fabeook.cmo";
var verimail = new Comfirm.AlphaMail.Verimail();

verimail.verify(email, function(status, message, suggestion){
    if(status < 0){
        // Incorrect syntax!
    }else{
        // Syntax looks great!
    }
});
```

Verimail.js even has a [jQuery plugin](https://github.com/comfirm/Verimail.js/blob/master/src/verimail.jquery.js) that is really easy to use:

```
$("input#email-address").verimail({
    messageElement: "p#status-message"
});
```